# Monotouch: Using DialogController Root element coupled with TableView on device being rotated

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, monotouch.dialog

I need to display different info depending on conditions.
I sometimes need Root element with sections and in other cases I need table view populated with data.
When I initialize Root element even empty one and then create a tableview when device is being rotated I have Root element on top and data from tableview.
How to preserve table view to stay on top?

Comment: It's not fully clear to me, could you add a screenshot of what you're getting ? e.g. before and after

Comment: The Root element content like sections and other elements in it were showed but the table with data disappeared.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just solved the problem overriding DidRotate method in view controller:

```
public overridevoid DidRotate (UIInterfaceOrientation fromInterfaceOrientation)
{
    // Stop event execution in order not to redraw some UI elements incorrectly
}
```